# Not getting proper response in Http Post call of web service

Tags: qt, symfony1

I am calling a webservice using Http Post method and getting below text in response

HTTP/1061.1061 1061 (I have printed QHttpResponseHeader in debug)

but in actual case it should return error code or xml. so please tell me what i am doing wrong in following code

```
//.cpp file code 
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  qDebug() << "start";
  http = new QHttp(this); // http declared as a member of MainWindow class
  connect(http, SIGNAL(requestFinished(int,bool)), SLOT(replyFinished(int, bool)));

  QByteArray data;//(QString("--" + boundary + "\r\n").toAscii());
  data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\n";

  data += "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n\r\n";

  data += QString("<LoginData><IMEI>test123</IMEI><email>a@a.com</email></LoginData>").toAscii();
  data += "\r\n";

  data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\"\r\n\r\n";

  data += "\r\n";

  QHttpRequestHeader header("Content-Type","application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
  header.setValue("Host", "http://xxx.com/restwebservice/ForgotPassword.ashx?");
  header.setValue("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
  header.setValue("Keep-Alive", "300");
  header.setValue("Connection", "keep-alive");
  header.setValue("Referer", "http://xxx.com/restwebservice/ForgotPassword.ashx?");

  qDebug() << "the sent data is :" + data;
  http->setHost("http://xxx.com/restwebservice/ForgotPassword.ashx?");
  http->request(header, data);

  ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

The slot method

```
void MainWindow :: replyFinished(int , bool)
{
    QHttpResponseHeader responce = http->lastResponse();
    qDebug()<<"reply is :" + responce.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QHttp` is deprecated and only still here for backward compatibility.

For new code, you should use `QNetworkAccessManager`/`QNetworkRequest`/`QnetworkReply` (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QNetworkAccessManager.html#details)

Comment: and one more thing....if i want to upload the image using web service then also this class will be used or i have to use QHttp.

Comment: Same classes. You'd use QNetworkAccessManager::post() with your data to upload.